# Count the number of times enter is pressed in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there really a way with which i could count the number of times, the enter key is pressed in a webpage. Not within an element say, a text box for an example, but rather the whole webpage. say if i open google.com and type something in the search box  and hit enter, so the count is one. as such, another search would give 2 enters pressed.any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: `java` + `jquery`? Maybe you mean `javascript`? Remember, [`java` is not `javascript`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

Comment: Sure it is possible. But out of interest: Why would you want to count the times enter is pressed? Does the first user to press enter 100times on your site win a price? ;-)

Comment: add a counter for everytime someone searches i'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using following approach:

```
var noOfCounts = 0;

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        noOfCounts ++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a JS event listener

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Specifically `keydown`.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    console.log(e.keycode);
});
```

Then figure out which [keycode](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/#article-header-id-1) you need and run your validation and other functions from there.